# how do we know indexes and the minus and positive numbers and when they end

Tags: indexing

Hi I am learning indexes with the -1,-2 etc I just wanted to know how do we know when the minus numbers end the positive numbers begin in. a say a list of 8 things, I get that it starts at positive 0,1,2 etc and from the end its -1,-2, but when do they end?

changing elements in a list

Comment: Are you asking *when numbers end*?  They don't.  (Though in any given system the "upper limit" is likely the maximum int for that system.  And you'd likely run into other problems long before reaching that size of an in-memory array.)

Comment: This behavior is specific per language. While python might have the concept of negative indices as "from the end", that's by no means standard. Regardless, you cannot iterate something without knowing the end, and to know that you either need to know what the it ends with, or the length of what you're iterating/accessing. Most languages opt for the latter.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give a little more context with your question; specifically if you could provide the programming language you're working with, and perhaps a specific example of code or use case that you're trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The indices point to an element of the array, they basically "count" the values. The negative indexing just means you start counting from the back.
Imagine this array containing the elements "A" to "E":

| my_array | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Accessing from the end | -5 | -4 | -3 | -2 | -1 |

Using python to create an example:

```py
my_array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

print(my_array[0]) # prints A
print(my_array[-5]) # also prints A
print(my_array[-1]) # prints E
print(my_array[4]) # also prints E
```

The positive and negative numbers are just ways of referencing an element of the array from the start vs. from the end. Every element can be accessed using a positive number as well as using a negative number. Neither of them ends (except when the array ends).

Comment: ok so they can all be positive or minus then?

Comment: Yes, they are all both positive and negative.